# How to read/get the text of the element which is in <div> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, cypress

I am new to cypress and Javascript, Please help me
I wanted to read the text inside the  tag and need to validate/assert that the text should be with the string "Saved" this div tag is the super child of <div role="row"...> tag

Below is the HTML code snippet

```
    <div ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)" ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" style="">
      <div role="row" ui-grid-row="row" row-render-index="rowRenderIndex" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-disable-selection ui-grid-coluiGrid-0009" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" id="1634105595764-0-uiGrid-0009-cell">
          <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">Saved</div></div>
```

But I am not able to get the element position, Please help me how to get the web element of the third div tag text

I used the above code but cypress throws an error

```
   cy.get(div).contains('Saved')
```

***Expected to find element: #31 634108833080-0-uiGrid-0009-cell > .ui-grid-cell-contents, but never found it.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the id at the end of the 3rd div, which has this expression

```js
id="1634105595764-0-uiGrid-0009-cell"
```

but the error message has a 3 in front **Expected to find element: #31 634108833080-0-uiGrid-0009-cell**.

so have you added `3` in the front of the selector to get the third item?

Maybe you want

```js
cy.get('div[role="gridcell"]')     // will give all cells
  .eq(2)                           // pick the 3rd cell (indexes start at 0)
  .contains('Saved')
```

or

```js
cy.get('div[role="gridcell"]')     // will give all cells
  .eq(2)                           // pick the 3rd cell (indexes start at 0)
  .find('.ui-grid-cell-contents')
  .contains('Saved')
```

These give you the inner-most div. If you want the `gridcell` div instead, add `.parent()`.

Comment: Thanks, but the id "#1634105595764-0-uiGrid-0009-cell" is dynamically generated, how to handle this? only common format is #xxxxxxxxx--0-uiGrid-0009-cell"

Comment: You can use `role` attribute instead, I'll update the example.

Comment: Don't forget there's `ng-repeat` on rows as well - did you already select the row, or are you iterating over all rows?

Answer (score 1):

In code example that you provided, is `div` some variable or what?

If I take your html snippet, load it with cypress and call `cy.get('div').contains('Saved').should('exist')` the test is successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use contains and then check if the text exists or is visible.

```js
cy.contains('.ui-grid-cell-contents', 'Saved').should('exist')
cy.contains('.ui-grid-cell-contents', 'Saved').should('be.visible')
```